# Pre_get_posts only show posts by administrator roles

Tags: wp-query, user-roles, pre-get-posts

I am trying to filter a query to only show posts that are posted by a user with the administrator role.

I've created a pre_get_posts action, and trying to use $query->set to filter the posts only in the category pages...

So far I have this

```
function remove_unvetted_authors() {
    $query->set( 'role', 'administrator' );
}

if (is_category()) {
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'remove_unvetted_authors' );
}
```

but it's throwing a 500 error.  I'm know 'role' isn't actually an arg for wp_query, but I can't find one that looks at the user role. :/

I also tried this:

```
function remove_unvetted_authors() {
    $ids = get_users( array('role' => 'administrator' ,'fields' => 'ID') );
    $query->set( 'author', '$ids' );
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'remove_unvetted_authors' );
```

But this also throws a 500 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a few issues with this code:

1. `$query` is not defined in your callback function.
2. `role` is not a valid argument for a query.
3. You're passing the `$ids` variable incorrectly.
4. To query for multiple authors you need to use `author__in`.
5. You're checking `is_category()` incorrectly.

For the first issue, the problem is that you're not getting `$query` from anywhere. You need to accept it as a parameter in the callback function:

```
function remove_unvetted_authors( $query ) {
    // $query->set( 'property', 'value' );
}
```

If you don't do that, `$query` is undefined, and trying to use `->set()` on an undefined variable will result in a 500 error. This is the issue responsible for that error code. But, even if you fix that it still won't work until you resolve the other issues.

For the second issue, you can't query posts by author role like that. You will need to do what you're trying in your second example and query the author ids.

For the third issue, you're passing `$ids` incorrectly. It's a variable, so shouldn't have quotes around it:

```
$query->set( 'author', $ids );
```

That wouldn't throw a 500 error, but it still won't work.

The fourth issue is that you can't query multiple authors with the `author` argument. You need to use `author__in`:

```
$query->set( 'author__in', $ids );
```

Lastly, you're using `is_category()` incorrectly. The way you've structured it now, `remove_unvetted_authors()` would apply to *all* queries when you're viewing a category.

This would include menus and widgets. But, as written, even that wouldn't work correctly. This is because `is_category()` will not work outside a hooked function, because whether or not it is a category hasn't been determined yet when functions.php is run.

You only want to affect the main category queries, and you only want to do it on the front-end. So you should check `is_admin()` and also `$query->is_category()`.

So after fixing all those issues, your code would look like this:

```
function remove_unvetted_authors( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_category() ) {
        $user_ids = get_users( [
            'role'   => 'administrator',
            'fields' => 'ID'
        ] );

        $query->set( 'author__in', $user_ids );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'remove_unvetted_authors' );
```

Comment: Wow thanks, this is a fantastic answer and the correct one!

Comment: Quick Question, if I wanted the role to be an array, including Administrator + Editor, how would it look?

Comment: Use `role__in`, with a value like `[ 'administrator', 'editor' ]`. The arguments for `get_users` are documented here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/prepare_query/

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove_unvetted_authors() {
    $ids = get_users( array('role' => 'administrator' ,'fields' => 'ID') );
    $query->set( 'author', '$ids' );
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'remove_unvetted_authors' );
```

This is going in the right direction but has a specific that is wrong. `'$ids'` - due to the single quotes, the variable does not get evaluated. Also [`get_users()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/#return) returns an **array**. [`author`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#author-parameters) expects an **int**.

Instead, with `author__in` (and no single quotes) it should work:

```
function remove_unvetted_authors() {
    $ids = get_users( array('role' => 'administrator' ,'fields' => 'ID') );
    $query->set( 'author__in', $ids );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try to check below code:

```
function remove_unvetted_authors() {
// Query user data on admins
$administrators = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' =>  'administrator' ) ); 

// Save admin IDs
foreach( $administrators->results as $u )
 $user_ids[] = $u->ID;

// Little cleanup
unset( $u, $administrators);

// Get all posts by these authors
$query = new WP_Query( array( 
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'author' => $user_ids 
) );
$posts = $query->posts;

//collect all post ids of that author by loop
$post_ids = array();
foreach($posts as $post) {
  $post_ids[] = $post->ID;    
}

$query->set('post__in', $post_ids);
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'remove_unvetted_authors' );
```

Comment: Why would you query `post__in` with _user_ ids?

Comment: user ids includes posts ids of administration and post__in include admin ids that have admin role and get those posts with pre_get_posts hook.

Comment: What? Your code is going to get posts with the same IDs as administrator users. That's completely wrong. They need to query posts whose _authors_ have those IDs.